# How to turn a list in a specific line in a .txt file into a list to run code on?

Tags: python

Basically, i'm trying to make a save and load system, and my game uses lists, floats, int, and strings, that are all written into a .txt file. When I load, the lists are now turned into strings, and I cannot append to them.
My code is:

```
#Sample txt file
1.5
'test'
['a','b','c']
['a1','a2','a3']
#My code:
 enter2 = [line.strip() for line in text_file.readlines()]
 unlocklist = enter2[22]
 text_file.close()
```

The problem with this is that it still gives me the string error, 'str' object has no attribute 'append'.
(The other lines don't matter, I have a seperate function that runs it.).
What should I do?

Comment: you could look into JSON for easy file saving and loading. Makes it a lot more robust

Comment: I don't really know json, so I can't really do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the list saved in your "text_file" is converted to string, that's why you are receiving error "'str' object has no attribute 'append'", to revert it back to list datatype, try the following code:

```
list_in_text_file = "['a1','a2','a3']"
remove_bracket= list_in_text_file[1:-1]
replaced_string = remove_bracket.replace("\'","")
enter2=replaced_string.split(",")
print(enter2) # your enter2 is now a list
```

Comment: You can implement this as a function so when you send a string, it gives you back a list. To check if a string is a list, check if first char is a [ and last char is ]. You can do that using `if list_in_text_file[0] == '[' and list_in_text_file[-1] == ']' then you can assume the string is a list. The assumption is based on the fact that your program is writing the lists into the file.